# Quartz not supporting JMX ?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am  trying to enable JMX on quartz and currently using following properties

```
 org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true
 org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName=quartz:type=SampleDBJobScheduler,name=Event Manager Thread, instanceId=AUTO
```

But i do not see its value in JConsole even when i am seeing quartz threads initialized and working correctly 
I am using JDBCJobStore for clustering 
and I am using 
a) Apache tomcat 8 
b) Java 8 
c) Quartz 2.2
d) Centos OS

[image]

Comment: Works for me in Quartz 2.3.2, are you sure Quartz is loading the property file you updated?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try without the property objectName: with only the property jmx.export=true you will see quartz in your jconsole.

After that, last chance, check that you target the good JVM.

Eric